# Getting error using Gdata to fetch google Docs file matadata

Tags: google-docs, gdata

From last day I am facing error in fetching Google Docs file matadata before its working fine.Now its showing me error.

```
Error Domain=com.google.GDataServiceDomain Code=404 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.GDataServiceDomain error 404.)"
```

my Code is

```
 NSURL *entryURL = [GDataServiceGoogleDocs metadataEntryURLForUserID:kGDataServiceDefaultUser];

    GDataServiceGoogleDocs *service = [self docsService];

    GDataServiceGoogleSpreadsheet *spreadsheetService;
    spreadsheetService = [[[GDataServiceGoogleSpreadsheet alloc] init] autorelease];

    GDataServiceGoogleDocs *docsService = [self docsService];
    [spreadsheetService setUserAgent:[docsService userAgent]];
    [spreadsheetService setUserCredentialsWithUsername:[docsService username]
                                              password:[docsService password]];

    [service fetchEntryWithURL:entryURL
             completionHandler:^(GDataServiceTicket *ticket, GDataEntryBase *entry, NSError *error) {
                 // callback
                 [self setMetadataEntry:(GDataEntryDocListMetadata *)entry];
                 if (error != nil) {
                     NSLog(@"Error fetching user metadata: %@", error);
                 }
             }];
```

Comment: Was it working properly earlier? As I am too facing the same issue.

Comment: I have same kind of error with GDataSpreadsheet. I opened a ticket here https://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/issues/detail?id=183. If you have updates let us know.

Comment: Have you solved the issue yet? I've encountered a similar one: Error Domain=com.google.GDataServiceDomain Code=404 "(null)"